# QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted pure virtual method calledterminate called without an active exception

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

I am working with ASP.NET MVC. PDF output is running in debug mode with Rotativa.But when I throw it to the server I get the above error.I tried all versions of rotativa and wkhtmltopdf.

If I don't add headers to the output it works well on both sides.

CustomSwitches = string.Format("--header-html "{0}" --header-spacing 10 --footer-html "{1}"", header, footer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the IP of the site to the host file. Problem solved.

See : https://cpanelplesk.com/how-to-edit-hosts-file-on-your-system/